# Read serial (/dev/tty*) fom java

Tags: java, linux, serial-port, tty

I am trying to read serial using Java:

```
    byte[] text = new byte[5];
    for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
        text[i] = (byte)in.read();
    }
```

For some reason it returns me some weird data. I have tried libraries like RXTX and COMM, but other issues comes then. Is there some way to read everything in raw Java way?
Any code snippets would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Please give an example of the data that you are getting and the data that you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Byte is just too narrow for this data serial data(because it is signed), so I do loose most significant bit. Solution is to read everything to int.